# Corrupt file downloads from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, download

Every time I try to download, it produces correct filename and extension (file) but corrupt (usually 1kb in size and can't be opened, in this case my file is .docx format and around 12kb in size). I'm using XAMPP, and I use phpmyadmin to look at my sql database. The upload script works to store file from computer to database.

Here is my upload script: - edited according to answers

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$nametemp=$_SESSION['name'];
$nistemp=$_SESSION['nislogin'];
$subjecttemp=$_SESSION['subject'];
$chapter=$_POST['chapter'];

$name=$_FILES['browsefile']['name'];
$mime=$_FILES['browsefile']['type'];
$data=file_get_contents($_FILES['browsefile']['tmp_name']);
$size=$_FILES['browsefile']['size'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO assignment (name, mime, size, data, created, uploader, subject, chapter) VALUES ('$name', '$mime', '$size', '$data', NOW(), '$nametemp', '$subjecttemp', '$chapter')");

header("location:subject.php");
die();
?>
```

and here's download script: -edited according to answers

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$nametemp=$_SESSION['name'];
$nistemp=$_SESSION['nislogin'];
$classtemp=$_SESSION['class'];
$subjecttemp=$_SESSION['subject'];
$idtemp=$_GET['id'];

$query=("SELECT mime, name, size, data FROM assignment WHERE id='$idtemp'");
$result=mysql_query($query);
$filename=mysql_result($result,0,"name");
$filesize=mysql_result($result,0,"size");
$filemime=$type=mysql_result($result,0,"mime");
$filedata=mysql_result($result,0,"data");

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-length: $filesize");
header("Content-type: $filemime");
header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");
echo $filedata;
?>
```

In case you're wondering, here is the screenshot of 'assignment' table structure: [image](http://s30.postimg.org/6sdbcmnq9/image.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

$data=$_FILES['browsefile']['tmp_name'];

You assign the temp name of an uploaded file to the 'data' column, not the data itself.
The quick-fix for this is to use file_get_contents function.

Second: readfile reads a file from the disk, it does not provide an output stream from a variable. This line is not needed.

But: saving a binary file in a database is not recommended. Beter to store the file itself in an upload folder and save the name of it.

Also, change the next line

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO assignment (name, mime, size, data, created, uploader, subject, chapter) VALUES ('$name', '$mime', '$size', '$data', NOW(), '$nametemp', '$subjecttemp', '$chapter')");
```

into

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO assignment (name, mime, size, data, created, uploader, subject, chapter) VALUES ('$name', '$mime', '$size', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($data) . "', NOW(), '$nametemp', '$subjecttemp', '$chapter')");
```

Next to this: please consider changing to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of using the old Mysql_* functions (they're deprecated).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, file_get_contents() is used when file is stored in the disk whereas mine is stored in database, I've tried changing echo $filedata to echo file_get_contents($filename) and what I get is a word document containing some php error code.

Comment: You upload the file to the disk (temporary), but you never insert it into the database. That's where file_get_contents() comes in: you need to use it in your upload file.
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['browsefile']['tmp_name']);

Comment: But I see in my table structure i have one file uploaded before i asked/changed my code the size column is 12952 (which is around 12kb) and data column says [BLOB - 21 B], wasn't that file successfully uploaded?

Comment: Sorry to double post. I have changed the code according to @Blaatpraat suggestion, it still does not provide complete file (usually some error php code in the word file and the size in in bytes not kilobytes). I guess the error is in the download script.

Comment: a quick update, i have tried changing the code according to @Blaatpraat 's answer, the file fail to upload and does not stored in the database.